# SMTP SocketException (0x2745) Error (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

I have a mail send script which is used to send out confirmations to users and staff when registrations occur etc. Of recent it seems we have been experiencing issues with the mail sending get very intermittent sends, and mainly erroring.

I've been working with the hoster to no avail. The exception is as follows:

```
   [SocketException (0x2745): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +6528783
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +130

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.]
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +296
   System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +45
   System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +106
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) +203
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) +16
   System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response) +54
   System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn) +28
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.OnClose(Object sender, EventArgs args) +8
   System.Net.ClosableStream.Close() +54
   System.Net.Mail.MailWriter.Close() +65
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1433
```

Now I have tried different authenticated users, different email contents and the common theme seems to be email with an attachment or emails with an HTML body seem prone to failure. My view is firmly that the mail server is the party that is disconnecting the request.

For reference I'm using asp.net 4.0 with a very standard set of code.

My hoster seems unable to locate or even resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Jon,may u show more code of your app please.From the stack seems that network connection has been closed.And i never seen it before.It is really strange. This line is the exception : [SocketException (0x2745): An established connection was aborted by the software in . I googled and i have found lot of link about it but there's no clear response.

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this. I will post my original code above shortly. I actually switched from using System.Mail.Net to using ASPEMAIL.NET by persits software. I ran the two side by side with the same body, subject, to and from and attachements. The system.net.mail failed intermittanly, the aspemail.net succeeded every time. The only thing i can conclude from this is that asp.net is throwing something nasty in the headers that our mailserver did not like. I still need to investigate it properly but this fixes the issue quickly for us.